# Teaching more users how our site works

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

On another Stack Exchange site I contribute to, I was surprised to learn how many high reputation contributors don't know about some of the key features of Stack Exchange, and many of the tools at their disposal to help make the site the best resource for that topic on the Internet.

As a result, [I'm now leaving comments, like this, on posts which either the community closes, or which I close](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/understanding-highlighted-processes-in-ritas-chart?noredirect=1#comment14609_12268):

> Hey Alex, you might be better served by focusing on one question at a time. As a Q&A site, it's harder to rate answers from highest to lowest if there are too many questions in a post. If one person knows the answer to #1 but not #2 or #3, that's a problem. Consider editing this post to focus on one of these. ***Just so you know, any edits to this post bump it into our [review queues](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review), where any user on our site with 500+ reputation can [review the post, edit, and vote to reopen](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).*** Hope this helps. — jmort253 ♦ 14 secs ago
>
> - Emphasis added here only

Specifically, I was surprised to learn how many people see closing as an end-game, that once a question is closed, that's it, end of story.  What we failed to teach people is that closing (or putting a question on hold) is the first in a series of steps designed to ultimately reopen that post in a newly minted, improved format. This is a win-win for the asker, a win for all the future readers searching for the same problem, and a win for our growing community.

The most important thing we can convey to the community is that *any closed post that gets edited is moved into the [reopen review queue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where it can be improved and given a second chance.*

Since not everyone on Project Management Stack Exchange finds their way to Meta PMSE, we can make an impact by leaving comments, such as the one above, anywhere where we can help give people the tools to make a positive impact on our site. Anyone can help leave these comments, even if you're new to our community!